# Singleton destructor called error

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
#pragma once
#include <time.h>        

class CTimer
{
    time_t _last;
    CTimer() { _last = time( NULL ); }
    CTimer(const CTimer &);
    CTimer& operator=(const CTimer&);
    ~CTimer();
public:
    static CTimer& getInstance(){        
        static CTimer instance;
        return instance;
    }

    float getDelta(){
        time_t now = time( NULL );
        float delta = (float)(now - _last);     
        return delta;
    }
    //should be called at the beginning of rendering function
    void update(){
        _last = time( NULL );
    }
};
```

This is my Timer singleton code. I wanted to use it like that:
Somewhere in player class:

```
posX += vel * CTimer::getInstance().getDelta();
```

And in main loop file:

```
void gameLoop(){
CTimer::getInstance().update();
...
}
```

But I get this error:

> 1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __thiscall CTimer::~CTimer(void)" (??1CTimer@@AAE@XZ) referenced in function "void _*cdecl `public: static class getInstance & __cdecl CTimer::getInstance(void)'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'instance''(void)" (??*_Finstance@?1??getInstance@CTimer@@SAAAV1@XZ@YAXXZ)

I think its because main code tries to call destructor, after loop ends and I should change to pointers singleton, but maybe not. Could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Did you provide a body for your destructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only member of your `CTimer` class is the `time_t` variable, then you don't need the (not implemented, hence the linking error) destructor, the copy constructor and the assignment operator. Just comment those three lines: these functions will be generated by the compiler !

Comment: If OP needs the destructor to be private, then commenting it out won't do.

Comment: Furthermore, a singleton should not have a copy constructor or an assignment operator.

Comment: True, my solution solves only the linkage problem(s), the best solution is to have them private, with empty implementations, to forbid other objects creation.

Answer (score 3):

Your singleton is destructed when `main` exits (if it was initialized of course). So it's destructor is called. You have to implement it (at least empty). Otherwise your program can not be linked

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an implementation for the destructor, since it is called when main returns:

```
~CTimer() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking destruction of object without writing body for destructor so it is leading to linking error.
Please write body of destructor

```
~CTimer()
    {} //code to free any resource
```

Example code:
http://ideone.com/TqtLVX#view_edit_box

Answer (score 0):

First: do you want the unique instance to be destructed or not?
If you want it to be destructed, you must either provide a body
for your destructor somewhere (even if it is empty), or you must
not declare it yourself (which would make it public, but that
shouldn't be a problem).  In C++11, you can also declare it `=
default`, which tells the compiler to generate what it would
normally generate for the implementation.

Most of the time, however, you don't want singleton's to be
destructed.  One of the main reasons for using a singleton is to
solve order of initialization problems; destructing it leaves
the door open to order of destruction issues.  The usual idiom
would be to use a static pointer to the singleton, testing
whether it is null in the instance function, and allocating
a new instance if it is.  (If I can believe the comment, which
suggests that this class is only used during rendering, it
probably doesn't matter, since you won't be doing anything with
the singleton once you've called `exit` or returned from
`main`.)